# How to hide model data from URL in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here is some code:

1.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/register", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String register(@RequestParam("name") String name,
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    // call to service
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "redirect:/success";
}
```

This endpoint gets hit first and registers the user with provided name and redirects to the success page. It also supplies the user name.

2.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/success", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String success(@ModelAttribute("name") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "success";
}
```

This endpoint changes the path in browser URL tab to `/success` and displays `success.html` template. It also sets the username in model so that on we can show on UI that `${name} registered successfully`.

`success.html` is a template in `/templates` folder, which we want to show once this operation is over on `/success` page.

Everything works as expected. The problem? name of the use shows up in URL on `/success` page.

So after registration, while we expect the URL to be just `/success`, it actually is `/success?name=John`. It is possible to hide the request parameter part? Or to send the data in body somehow rather than request parameter.

Thanks in advance, let me know if any other detail is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. It can be done for example by using `redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("name", name)` instead of `redirectAttributes.addAttribute("name", name)` in the first controller.

You can get more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/html/web.html#mvc-flash-attributes).